# How to access a variable state from before an ajax request in the call back function

Tags: javascript

EG

```
for(i in an_object){

        $.getJSON("http//www...." + "?callback=?",'', function(data){
                // do something using what the value of i from when the JSONP request was sent
                // but i is always the last value in an_object because the loop 
                // has finished by the time the callback runs.
            );
        });
}
```

Comment: see possible duplicates - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript+closures+loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by putting the ajax call inside an anonymous function. eg:

```
for(i in an_object){

    (function(i){

        $.getJSON("http//www...." + "?callback=?",'', function(data){
                // i now remembers its state.
        });
    })(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need one variable, you can bind it as context to the function using proxy:

```
var state=1, callbackfunction = function(data) {
  if (this===1) {
    //something based on state
  }
}

$.getJSON("http//www..",'', jQuery.proxy( callbackfunction , state) );
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I found a better solution that accepts any number of parameters - see my answer.